# Java cast by using return value from .getClass()

Tags: java

I would like to create a cast as follows

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal { //Dog inherits Animal
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Object d = new Dog();
        System.out.println(d.getClass()); // "Dog"
        ((d.getClass()) d).print();
        /**
         * 4.253.25/Dog1.java:8: error: ')' expected
         * ((d.getClass()) d).print();
         * ^
         * 4.253.25/Dog1.java:8: error: not a statement
         * ((d.getClass()) d).print();
         * ^
         * 4.253.25/Dog1.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
         * ((d.getClass()) d).print();
         * ^
         * 4.253.25/Dog1.java:8: error: ';' expected
         * ((d.getClass()) d).print();
         * ^
         * 4 errors
         **/
    }
}
```

Is there a possible way to do it without explicitly saying cast it to Dog (instanceof Dog I also count as explicitly) that actually works?

Comment: Write an interface with your `print` method, have `Dog` implement it, and cast to that. If you want to cast something to make a method accessible at _compile time_, you can't do it by using a type that is not known until run-time.

Comment: Use `cast()` method of `Class`: `d.getClass().cast(d)`. edit: but will not do what you want probably. Create an interface as mentioned in comment above

Comment: Define `print` as `abstract` method in your `Animal` class, or better make Animal an `interface`, as already advised.

Comment: No, not possible, just: `class Animal {public void print() {}} ... Animal d = new Dog();` In java **proxy** classes have such a polymorphic freedom.

Comment: Ward his proposal didn't work out, so I think Joop Eggen is probably right. Thought there is maybe a way to do it :/ - anyway was just something I had in mind - not further important anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast your object to `Dog` and call its `print` method.

If you want to use the class metadata, you can't directly call print, because you are getting the class at runtime, so at compile time the compiler doesn't know what actual class your object `d` is. So, instead, you'll have to use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to invoke the method at runtime. This way of invoking the method is slower than doing it at compile time (i.e. the normal way).

```
    Object d = new Dog();
    ((Dog) d).print();
    d.getClass().getMethod("print").invoke(d);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cast your object to a Dog, casting it to an Animal is enough:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Object d = new Dog();
        System.out.println(d.getClass()); // "Dog"
        ((Animal) d).print();
}
```

will print

```
Dog
Dog
```

Comment: Yeah, but I was interested if it will be possible to ask for the class during runtime and do the cast afterwards by using the result.

Comment: Besides casting to Animal can't work when Animal does not know the method print().